# Retrieving max week number minus 2 for each month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to retrieve the max week number of each month minus 2, with week numbers year-to-date minus 2.

```
Sample data

January    Feb
Week 1     Week 5
Week 2     Week 6
Week 3     Week 7
Week 4     Week 8
```

Output:

```
January    Feb
Week 1     Week 1
Week 2     Week 2
           Week 3
           Week 4
           Week 5
           Week 6
```

So for Jan, the max week number is week 4, therefore we take week 1 and week 2.

For Feb, the max week number is week 8, therefore we take week 1 to week 6 as week 6 is 8-2.

Schema is as follows:

```
Date (daily)
Year
Month
Week

Example
Date           Year      Month      Week
05/01/2019     2019      January    1
```

Hope this makes sense?

Thanks!

afk

Comment: how does the table schema looks like ? Are you having one column for each month ? Please show us the table schema

Comment: What are these weeks based on as well? Every 7 days into the year? When a specific day (Monday maybe) is reached? If the latter, then the positions of the weeks will change depending on the year; which means you should have year data too.

Comment: Don't post that informatoin in the comments @afk we can't read it as you can't format text in them. Include the information in your question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55828338/edit) it please. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I've added them to my original question.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: So, are you saying your source data looks like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cbe4b22768c421f6c28513a85f397e63)?

Comment: Hi @Larnu, yes that's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left out the dates as your `Week` numbering may be different, but the principle is the same if you already have the `Week` number in your source data.  All you need to do is find the `max` `Week` number by `Month`, then using a self `join` return all `Week` values in the same year with a lesser value:

```
declare @t table([Year] int,[Month] varchar(15),[Week] int);
insert into @t values(2019,'January',1),(2019,'January',2),(2019,'January',4),(2019,'February',5),(2019,'February',6),(2019,'February',7),(2019,'February',8),(2019,'March',9),(2019,'March',10),(2019,'March',11),(2019,'March',12),(2019,'March',13);

with m as
(
    select [Year]
          ,[Month]
          ,max([Week])-2 as MaxWeek
    from @t
    group by [Year]
            ,[Month]
)
select m.[Year]
      ,m.[Month]
      ,t.[Week]
from @t as t
    join m
        on t.[Year] = m.[Year]
            and t.[Week] <= m.MaxWeek
order by m.[Year]
        ,m.[Month]    -- Replacing this with your actual date value should give you correct sorting
        ,t.[Week];
```

## Output

```
+------+----------+------+
| Year |  Month   | Week |
+------+----------+------+
| 2019 | February |    1 |
| 2019 | February |    2 |
| 2019 | February |    4 |
| 2019 | February |    5 |
| 2019 | February |    6 |
| 2019 | January  |    1 |
| 2019 | January  |    2 |
| 2019 | March    |    1 |
| 2019 | March    |    2 |
| 2019 | March    |    4 |
| 2019 | March    |    5 |
| 2019 | March    |    6 |
| 2019 | March    |    7 |
| 2019 | March    |    8 |
| 2019 | March    |    9 |
| 2019 | March    |   10 |
| 2019 | March    |   11 |
+------+----------+------+
```